# Why is my array not visible in my PHP include file?

Tags: php

I have a main page where I declare an array an add values:

```
<?php
  $items = array();
  $items[] = "one";
  $items[] = "two";
  $items[] = "three";
  include("http://mydomain.net/process.php);
?>
```

In the file `process.php` I have:

```
<?php
  foreach($items as $item) {
    print $item;
  }
?>
```

The problem is that nothing gets printed. When I move the assignments for the array into `process.php` everything works as expected. What I find odd is that I did the same thing on another site, and there it works. What am I missing here?

Comment: Try changing `include("mydomain.net/process.php");` to `include('process.php');`, include() is for files that exist on the local file system only, you shouldn't include files over http (I don't even think you can)

Comment: For debugging, you might want to change "include" to "require". That way, it'll error out if it can't find the file.

Comment: To add to @zajd's comment, if you `include` via HTTP then that's a completely separate web request, and the global context of `$items` does not get taken with it.

Comment: @zajd - Thanks for the advice. Apparently you *can* include files over HTTP; like I said I got output from the print function if I assigned the array inside the include file.

Comment: @ChrisForrence - Thanks for the tip. It doesn't seem to be the issue here (the file *is* included), but I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @stevenvh I suspect you are including over HTTP, but that page over HTTP is going to be the output of the script as run by Apache, which is why it's only showing you things that you print in the included file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass a url you will have to include the full url (including http://). Give it the path to your file instead.

```
include("/path/to/file/process.php");
```

See [example 3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) from the manual.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran which makes only sense if the webserver would return PHP code, what it doesn't.

Comment: Not only that. This feature must be enabled on the PHP configuration. Otherwise you have no access to add URL-based includes (http-wrappers must be enabled).